# PAM requires password for exec/shell_exec even with NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers

Tags: php, nginx, exec, sudo, archlinux

**What I'm trying to do:**

Permit the web server user (http) to run either an explicit iptables command or (preferrably) a script that checks the input for syntax before passing it to iptables without the need for a password.

**The problem:**

In spite of all my searching of the issue at hand, no changes to visudo, sudoers.d or php configurations appear to make a difference for what I'm trying to do.

**The relevant conditions of my server:**

```
[weasel@darwyn ~]$ uname -a
Linux darwyn 5.3.7-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 18 00:17:03 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux

nginx version: nginx/1.16.1

PHP 7.3.10 (cli) (built: Sep 26 2019 13:40:03) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.10, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

Username:                           http
UID:                                33
Gecos field:
Home directory:                     /srv/http
Shell:                              /usr/bin/nologin
No login:                           yes
Primary group:                      http
GID:                                33
Hushed:                             no
Running processes:                  3

Last logs:
09:29 sudo[648]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [http]
09:29 sudo[649]: pam_unix(sudo:account): account http has expired (account expired)
09:29 sudo[650]: pam_unix(sudo:account): account http has expired (account expired)
```

**Steps I've taken to fix the issue:**

- ***I have enabled debugging in PHP-FPM.***

/var/log/php-fpm.log tells me that the calls are being initiated but expecting a password:

```
"sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper"
```

- ***I have made changes to visudo.***

From similar questions I learned that the sudoers file prioritizes the last configuration related to a user.  So where I first had

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
weasel ALL=(ALL) ALL
http ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/blacklist_ip, /usr/bin/iptables
```

I moved the entry down to

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
weasel ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

## Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to execute any command
# %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Uncomment to allow any user to run sudo if they know the password
## of the user they are running the command as (root by default).
# Defaults targetpw  # Ask for the password of the target user
# ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL  # WARNING: only use this together with 'Defaults targetpw'

##
##  Relocated user http permissions for testing
##
http ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/blacklist_ip, /usr/bin/iptables

## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

- ***I have made changes to /etc/sudoers.d/90-MyOverrides.***

I removed the http entry in visudo and moved it to /etc/sudoers.d/90-MyOverrides.

- ***I have tried variations of the sudoers rules.***

```
http ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/blacklist_ip, /usr/bin/iptables
http ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/blacklist_ip, /usr/bin/iptables
http ALL=(http:http) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/blacklist_ip, /usr/bin/iptables
http ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/blacklist_ip *, /usr/bin/iptables *
http ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/blacklist_ip *, /usr/bin/iptables *
http ALL=(http:http) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/blacklist_ip *, /usr/bin/iptables *
http ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/iptables -L
http ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/iptables -L
http ALL=(http:http) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/iptables -L
```

To make sure this was having some sort of effect, I tested it on my own user

```
weasel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/iptables
```

I was able to execute iptables commands without a password as user weasel, but the php-fpm log was still requiring a password for user http.
I also attempted the command using 'sudo -S' in the hope that a null value for the password would work, however it also errors out.

```
"[sudo] password for http: "
"sudo: no password was provided"
```

- ***I have double-checked access to the exec/shell_exec functions in the php configurations.***

I checked both /etc/php/php.ini and /etc/php/php-fpm.conf to ensure that the exec/shell_exec commands weren't disabled and that safe mode wasn't active.  The resulting debug information in /var/log/php-fpm.log already proves this, but I wanted to be thorough.

- ***I have temporarily chowned the script to user http.***

This was a bit redundant, but just to void out the possibility that it mattered.

- ***I have tried variations of the exec/shell_exec calls.***

```
exec("sudo blacklist_ip 185.189.12.135");
shell_exec("sudo blacklist_ip 185.189.12.135");
return:
"sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper"

exec("blacklist_ip 185.189.12.135");
shell_exec("blacklist_ip 185.189.12.135");
exec("/usr/bin/iptables -A INPUT -s 185.189.12.135 -j DROP");
shell_exec("/usr/bin/iptables -A INPUT -s 185.189.12.135 -j DROP");
return:
"Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied"

exec("sudo /usr/bin/iptables -A INPUT -s 185.189.12.135 -j DROP");
shell_exec("sudo /usr/bin/iptables -A INPUT -s 185.189.12.135 -j DROP");
return:
"sudo: Account expired or PAM config lacks an "account" section for sudo, contact your system administrator"
```

- **I noticed the PAM config error.**

And with a bit of searching found that according to https://www.sudo.ws/troubleshooting.html:

> Q) Sudo says 'Account expired or PAM config lacks an "account" section for sudo, contact your system administrator' and exits but I know my account has not expired.
>   A) Your PAM config lacks an "account" specification.  On Linux this usually means you are missing a line like:
>       account    required    pam_unix.so
>   in /etc/pam.d/sudo.

No one ever mentions this as a cause in any other Q&A related to this topic.  Nevertheless, for the sake of thoroughness [I looked up information regarding PAM and sudo](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_smart_cards/pam_configuration_files#Sample_PAM_Configuration_Files):

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            include         system-auth
account         required        pam_unix.so
#account        include         system-auth
session         include         system-auth
```

It made no difference.

I am out of ideas.  I need more information on an appropriate PAM module, making the http user passable by PAM or I need some redirection for further assessment.

**EDIT**
Updated to simplify the information for the sake of brevity.

**EDIT**
Added contents of /etc/php/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
[www]

user = http
group = http

listen = /run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock

listen.owner = http
listen.group = http

pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 5

pm.start_servers = 2

pm.min_spare_servers = 1

pm.max_spare_servers = 3


access.log = /var/log/php/$pool.access.log

access.format = "%R - %u %t \"%m %r%Q%q\" %s %f %{mili}d %{kilo}M %C%%"

catch_workers_output = yes

php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Comment: Geez. That's a lot of information. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/passwd | grep http` ?

Comment: @Daan http:x:33:33::/srv/http:/usr/bin/nologin though I will note the output of lslogin shown at the top of my question gives all of this information

Comment: @Weaselgrease `grep user /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is set to `http` then?

Comment: @Daan
[weasel@darwyn ~]$ grep user /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user http;
http         491  0.0  0.3  80744 11940 ?        S    08:11   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
http         492  0.0  0.3  80808 12360 ?        S    08:11   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
http         496  0.0  0.2  41600  7860 ?        S    08:12   0:01 nginx: worker process

Comment: I see your using PHP-FPM, can you post your www.conf too?

Comment: When running your script from the browser (<= not CLI!). What does `shell_exec('whoami')` return?

Comment: @Daan Updated my question with the www.conf file's uncommented values.  Also, the output of whoami within a shell_exec in the browser returns 'http'.  That was a good question.

Comment: And what does `chage -l http` return?

Comment: @Daan
Last password change                                    : Oct 07, 2019
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : Jan 02, 1970
Minimum number of days between password change          : -1
Maximum number of days between password change          : -1
Number of days of warning before password expires       : -1

Comment: The http account is expired at Jan 02, 1970. That should be set to never or at least in the future. You can set that with `chage -E -1 http`

Comment: @Daan Is it odd that this is set by the system when creating the http user?  So far as I know I haven't performed any actions to modify this expiry date.

Comment: @Weaselgrease I'm not sure how you've created the account. You could check your `/etc/login.defs` file. That file specifies defaults for new accounts

Comment: @Daan it appears that your suggestion to check the chage for the account has helped!  I changed the account expiry to never to solve it.  Do you want to submit it as an answer, or should I?

Comment: @Weaselgrease You go ahead and submit it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Daan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509304/pam-requires-password-for-exec-shell-exec-even-with-nopasswd-in-etc-sudoers#comment103347897_58509304) in the comments, it turns out that at some point the http account's expiry date was set to a time far in the past so that it was functionally never useable for sudo commands.  Perhaps this was a decision to future-proof a system against the possibility of injected exec/shell_exec commands by use of PHP in a web server.

***The solution:***

[Daan then recommended a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509304/pam-requires-password-for-exec-shell-exec-even-with-nopasswd-in-etc-sudoers#comment103348012_58509304)

```
chage -E -1 http
```

This set the user's expiry to 'never' and made it useable again.  The sudo settings now work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not giving your question answer but related to this one and feels worth mentioning here. I came across to similar issue when using

`GitHub actions to run sudo command in your-file-name.yaml file`

All the script runs successfully, but at the end when it runs

`sudo supvervisor restart all`

it fails due to the password required for sudo command and returns an error `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

**Bellow is the procedure to solve this issue:**

You can add your `your-user-name` to the sudoer group if not exit by using the following command:

`sudo adduser your-user-name sudo`

Now you can tell the system to add it as no password required user

`sudo sh -c "echo 'your-user-name ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers"`